# accessing variables from functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

how can i access a variable that was intialsed in a function, but the main.name is giving me a null value, i know the value is initliased in the function, or on main, but not in the feed!! this is my example,

```
var main = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

var feed = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

    title:'feeds',
    url:'main_windows/feeds.js',
    barImage:'bg_content.gif',
    username:main.name //im trying too access this varibale from main.

});

Ti.App.addEventListener('grantEntrance',function(event)
{

    main.title ='Welcome'+event.username;
    main.url = 'main_windows/main.js';
    main.name = event.username; // this is where the varibale is intialised
    main.email = event.email;
    main.barImage='bg_content.gif';

});
```

sorry if this seems like a stupid question but im a newbie to javascript, so just tell me to delete it. i was wondering if you can turn it into a gloab or something.

Comment: It seems to me you're simply trying to access the variable before you initialize it...

Comment: i tried to put it after the intilaisation, but i still get an NULL!!! :((

Comment: Welcome to javascript.  Get ready for a lot of questions like this.  My general advice, is first try to recreate the problem using as few lines of code as posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get variable that is not initialized yet. Since you're assigning main.name in a callback of event it will be initialized only after that event is fired. I'm not sure what's the logic of you'r application, but I guess you're able to initialize window inside this callback:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('grantEntrance',function(event) {
    main.title ='Welcome'+event.username;
    main.url = 'main_windows/main.js';
    main.name = event.username;
    main.email = event.email;
    main.barImage='bg_content.gif';

    var feed = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title:'feeds',
        url:'main_windows/feeds.js',
        barImage:'bg_content.gif',
        username:main.name
    });
});
```

Or, just set username property of the window inside callback:

```
var feed = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'feeds',
    url:'main_windows/feeds.js',
    barImage:'bg_content.gif',
});

Ti.App.addEventListener('grantEntrance',function(event) {
    main.title ='Welcome'+event.username;
    main.url = 'main_windows/main.js';
    main.name = event.username;
    main.email = event.email;
    main.barImage='bg_content.gif';

    feed.username = main.name
});
```

Also, from personal experience: Titanium is not the best way to "fill the power" of js: some of methods are running asynchroniusly, and it causes weird issues. So if you're newbie it could be a pain in the ass..

Anyway good luck :)